# How to loop over HTTP response in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to get some information on the internet. I then loop over that response and print it.

Loop here:

```
<% @responses.each do |response| %>
  <%= response %>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
["total", 1]
["page", 0]
["page_size", 500]
["result", [{"token_address"=>"0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e"}]]
```

How would I grab the token address here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `@responses` is a hash, so:

```
token_address = @responses['result'].first['token_address']
```

It depends on what else could be in the array...

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I modified it to @responses["result"]["token_address"] and it worked. However, I'm not dealing with a slightly different issue. Please have a look at this Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QrFzC1eW. If I do @responses["result"]["metadata"] I'm now dealing with a string. How would I get the "Name" instead the metadata?

Comment: You're welcome. The metatdata is JSON, so `parsed = JSON.parse(@responses['result']['metadata']); parsed['name']`.